# SocketIO: Transmit position data results in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am building a multiplayer application in which there is one object that all participants can move equally. Now when someone moves the object, this triggers the client's event again which results in a loop (and lagging). How can I prevent the client from transmitting the event again and instead just receiving it. Below is my architecture which is clearly wrong for that scenario.

app.js

```
// store old position
var oldPosX = obj.x;
setInterval(function() {
    //check if new movement
    if (oldPosX !== obj.x) {
        // send new pos to the server
        socket.emit('clientMoves', {
            x: obj.x
        });
        oldPosX = obj.x;
    }
}, 100);
```

server.js

```
socket.on('clientMoves', function(movementData) {
    // send clients new pos to all clients in users room
    socket.to(players[socket.id].playerRoom).emit('newPos', movementData);
});
```

app.js

```
//if we receive new data from the server then use it
socket.on('newPos', function(pos) {
    obj.x = pos.x;
});
```

[image]

Comment: You're never updating `oldPosX` inside the interval?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I forgot it for the example. Updated it now.

Comment: So to be clear, when the client that emits `clientMoves` received the `newPos` event (due to its own movement), it will send `clientMoves` again? That would only happen if `obj.x` doesn't strict-equal `oldPosX`.

Comment: Yes. When inserting a `console.log()`  into the `newPos-Event`, then I'm receiving this log message in the console of the client I'm moving my object. But this client only should send data and not receiving his own data. A position data can look like this `2.2442456732`.

Comment: You can't prevent a client from receiving that message. You can send a client id along with the data so clients can check if they were the one sending the message.

Comment: I tried that now but it has no effect. Client-A moves the object --> Client-A posNew and posOld are different so it emits the event --> Client-B receiving the new data and sets position to newPos --> Client-B posNew and posOld are different so it emits the event again (this shouldnt happen) --> Client-A receiving that data but now oldPos and newPos are the same so it stops. So after moving the object on Client-A i will receive an event from Client-B (and so id from client-b).

Comment: I have added a flow chart in the op.

Comment: Ah right, now I understand the issue. Instead of using an interval and an "old" position, can't you emit the `clientMoves` event only when a participant moves the object? So not depending on `obj.x` changing value, but on user input.

Comment: Alternatively, when a client receives the `newPos` event, update both `oldPosX` and `obj.x` in each client.